# What is the time complexity of adding a list of words to a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, time-complexity

I have the following code

```
    # Dictionary containing words and their frequencies
    word_freq = {}
    
    # Adding each word in the dictionary, and updating the frequency
    for word in words:
        if word in word_freq:
            word_freq[word] += 1
        else:
            word_freq[word] = 1
```

I'm trying to understand what the worst case time complexity of the above code would be.
By my understanding, this should be O(n^2). You're looping over each of the input, and for each input you're adding it to the hashmap/dict. The worst case time complexity for insert in a hashmap is O(n). So I'm thinking this is O(n^2).
Thoughts?

Comment: "Yes". Note that ``collections.Counter`` already offers this pattern out of the box.

Comment: "The worst case time complexity for insert in a hashmap is O(n)." - you would hardly come into such a situation if not actively trying to, the average is O(1),